# How to change the color of an old photo to real color in python

Tags: python

Hi I would like to know how can I change the color of an old black and white photo to real color with python.

I have tried and I don't know how to do it, I need help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have posted a way to do it as an answer, but you don't describe your issue in the post, why do you fail in coloring the photo? do you have an error code or something

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of dong it:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from cv2 import dnn

proto_file = 'Model\colorization_deploy_v2.prototxt'
model_file = 'Model\colorization_release_v2.caffemodel'
hull_pts = 'Model\pts_in_hull.npy'
img_path = 'images/img1.jpg'


#Reading the model params
net = dnn.readNetFromCaffe(proto_file,model_file)
kernel = np.load(hull_pts)


#Reading and preprocessing image
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
scaled = img.astype("float32") / 255.0
lab_img = cv2.cvtColor(scaled, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)


# add the cluster centers as 1x1 convolutions to the model
class8 = net.getLayerId("class8_ab")
conv8 = net.getLayerId("conv8_313_rh")
pts = kernel.transpose().reshape(2, 313, 1, 1)
net.getLayer(class8).blobs = [pts.astype("float32")]
net.getLayer(conv8).blobs = [np.full([1, 313], 2.606, dtype="float32")]

# we'll resize the image for the network
resized = cv2.resize(lab_img, (224, 224))
# split the L channel
L = cv2.split(resized)[0]
# mean subtraction
L -= 50


# predicting the ab channels from the input L channel

net.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(L))
ab_channel = net.forward()[0, :, :, :].transpose((1, 2, 0))
# resize the predicted 'ab' volume to the same dimensions as our
# input image
ab_channel = cv2.resize(ab_channel, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))


# Take the L channel from the image
L = cv2.split(lab_img)[0]
# Join the L channel with predicted ab channel
colorized = np.concatenate((L[:, :, np.newaxis], ab_channel), axis=2)

# Then convert the image from Lab to BGR
colorized = cv2.cvtColor(colorized, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
colorized = np.clip(colorized, 0, 1)

# change the image to 0-255 range and convert it from float32 to int
colorized = (255 * colorized).astype("uint8")

# Let's resize the images and show them together
img = cv2.resize(img,(640,640))
colorized = cv2.resize(colorized,(640,640))

result = cv2.hconcat([img,colorized])

cv2.imshow("Grayscale -> Colour", result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I don't get an error, but it doesn't change the color of the original photo to the colored photo, I get the same photo with the same color both of them.

Comment: Can you share your images and code?

Comment: The code is medium long and does not let me, I share it by mail or how.

Comment: I'm new to this site and I still don't know how it's going at all

Comment: Can you post some of it?